# Unit testing models that use validators with injected dependencies

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, ninject, ninject.web.mvc

I'm using a custom validator on some of my models in a MVC 5 application.  This validator has a dependency on a service that is injected via a property with the Ninject.MVC3 package. (See https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/wiki/Injection-of-validators)

This is what the validator looks like:

```
public class StrongPasswordAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    [Inject]
    public IConfigurationProvider Configuration { get; set; }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        return Configuration.GetPasswordPolicy().IsValid(value.ToString());
    }
}
```

The injection works fine in the application, but I want to unit test the models that use this validator.  This is my usual method of triggering the validation of `model`:

```
ValidationContext context = new ValidationContext(model, null, null);
List<ValidationResult> results = new List<ValidationResult>();

bool isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(model, context, results, true);
```

At this point it fails because the Configuration property is `null`.

Is there a way to manually inject a (mocked) object into the attribute for the duration of the test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I recommend split testing.

First, can write a test, which would test `PasswordPolicy` or `StrongPasswordAttribute`:

```
[Test]
public void PasswordPolicy_should_reject_short_passwords()
{
   PasswordPolicy policy = new PasswordPolicy();
   bool result = policy.Validate("pwd");
   Assert.IsFalse(result);
}
```

Second, make sure that some property of model marked with `StrongPasswordAttribute` attribute:

```
[Test]
public void Password_in_SomeModel_should_be_marked_StrongPasswordAttribute()
{
    Type type = typeof(SomeModel);

    bool hasAttribute = // use reflection here
    Assert.IsTrue(hasAttribute)
}
```

Comment: I was leaning toward this method, and ended up using it for now.  The only hangup here was that my other tests for this model were failing because of the lack of injected property.  So, I added a condition to the IsValid() method in the attribute to check for existence of the service.  (It returns false (invalid) if the service isn't injected.)